# Downloading PDF file using meteor

Tags: meteor

We wanted to download PDF files using:

`http://username:password@myapp.com/Folder/client.pdf`

How can I achieve this using meteor?

I have added the recommendation below to the `router.js`:

https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-tuto-routerAndFileDownload/blob/master/tuto-routerAndImage.js

But getting this error on the browser:

> Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: Npm is not defined

Answer (score 0):

## Download File in Meteor

Base on iron router documentation you can use this.

## Apache servicng static file

If you want to force to download you can use .htaccess.

Router.js 
`Router.route('/Folder/:filename', function () {
  this.response.end('some file content\n');
}, {where: 'server'});`

Download.html 
`<a href="/Folder/myfilename">Download File</a>`

Why Npm is not defined i appearing.
You must run the router with `where: 'server'`

Comment: Still getting NPM not found error:
Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: Npm is not defined

Router.route('mobileFiles/:id', 'GET',  function funcDisplayAnnoncesImage(id) { 
 var fstream = Npm.require('fs'),
 filename = 'public/mobileApp/test_gs_working_field_read.pdf',
 response = this.response,
 filestream;
    
 if (!fstream.existsSync(filename)) {
  console.log('router image not found', filename);
  return [404];
 }

 return [200, {'Content-Type':'application/pdf'}, fstream.readFileSync(filename)];
 }, {where: 'server'});

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the previous response.
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'existsSync' at [object Object].funcDisplayAnnoncesImage (lib/router.js:263:15) at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1) at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1) at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:123:1 at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/root/.meteor/packages/iron_router/.1.0.13.qto935++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:84:40) at 
...

Comment: What is the version of your Meteor? if lower 1.2 please install 
meteorhacks:npm  and the NPM can works great

according to https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

the `existsSync` is deprecated and you can use
`fs.accessSync(path[, mode])`

In your code change to var `fs = Npm.require('fs')`

Example:

`fs.access('/etc/passwd', fs.R_OK | fs.W_OK, function (err) {
  console.log(err ? 'no access!' : 'can read/write');
});`

or

`fs.accessSync(path[, mode])`

Synchronous version of fs.access.